# Present a UIViewController from a UIHostingViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uihostingcontroller

I'm starting to rebuild my app from `Swift` to `SwiftUI`.

I have one `UIViewController` that is built using `UIPresentationController` and has custom drag gestures that I would like to use as-is (for now).

I'm trying to figure out if I am able to present this from my `SwiftUI` View.

Here is how I navigate to the SwiftUI view:

```
let dataStore = DataStore()
let vc = Host(rootView: SwiftUIView(store: dataStore))
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

The method to present my controller is in my DataStore.

Here is what I am trying:

```
func displayDetailController(forData data: Data?) {
     let height = // I set a custom height here as I can drag 
     //this view to pop to the middle, to the top, or dismiss
     guard let dat = data else { return }
     let const = DetailViewController.Constructor(data: dat)
     let vc = DetailViewController.loadFromNib(constructor: const, height: height) 
        
     let hostingController = Host(rootView: SwiftUIView(store: self))
     hostingController.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

I have a `Button` that when tapped will call `displayDetailController` but nothing happens.

The goal being my DetailViewController is presented and I can see my data and use the drag gestures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're creating a new `Host` and `SwiftUIView` and trying to present from them. But, they aren't part of the view hierarchy, so nothing gets presented.

Instead, you probably want to pass a reference to your *actual* view controller. This code is incomplete, since you didn't include definitions for everything, but it should get you started:

```
let dataStore = DataStore()
dataStore.navigationController = self.navigationController
let vc = Host(rootView: SwiftUIView(store: dataStore))
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

```
class DataStore {
  var navigationController : UINavigationController?

  // other code

  func displayDetailController(forData data: Data?) {
     let height = 100
     guard let dat = data else { return }
     let const = DetailViewController.Constructor(data: dat)
     let vc = DetailViewController.loadFromNib(constructor: const, height: height) 
     self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Ha, can't believe I overlooked this. Thank you so much. I'll checkmark it when SO allows me to in a few minutes. Thanks!